# ¿Imprimir distintos colores en un mismo stringstream usando ncurses? C++

Tags: c++, string, color

Estoy trabajando en un código.

Quiero que me imprima (**únicamente**) el número en rojo si es negativo y en verde si es positivo.

Estoy utilizando **ncurses** y, por la estructura del programa, utilizo un único **stringstream** para los distintos números. De manera que si cambio el color con:

```
start_color();
init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);
init_pair(2, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLACK);
attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
```

Me imprime toda la pantalla de color rojo, cuando yo únicamente quiero el número.

Por lo tanto, mi string es algo así:

```
stringstream_var << "Number 1: " << num1 << std::endl;
stringstream_var << "Number 2: " << num2 << std::endl;
```

Y luego lo imprimo en pantalla.

He probado con códigos hexadecimales y ANSI para colorear el número, pero no funciona con ncurses.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para lograr esto?

Comment: ¿ Has probado con los [código de color ANSI](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_escape_ANSI) ? Casi todas las terminales de Linux los soportan.

Comment: Si, pero no funcionan con ncurses

Comment: Claro, con toda la lógica del mundo. Tienes que escoger: o `ncurses` y sus funciones (sin poder usar el `stringstream`), o directo al terminal (sin usar `ncurses`).

Comment: Me da a mí que me quedo sin colorear los numeritos, porque por la estructura del programa necesito hacerlo con ncurses y stringstreams.

Comment: Igual no, puedes hacerte una función o un `operator` o algo para *volcar* el `stringstream`. Claro, con todo el *curro* que implica :-) Una especie de *parser* que interprete ciertos caracteres de forma especial.

Comment: Por ejemplo, si encuentra un `0x01`, los siguientes 2 números indican el color. Y que llame a `ncurses` en consecuencia.

Comment: Pero creo que seguiría teniendo el mismo problema, al intentar colorearlo, me colorearía toda la variable stringstream_var

Comment: No, las `curses` pueden colorear solo 1 caracter. Hace **mucho, mucho** tiempo que no las *toco* y no te puedo ser de mas ayuda. Pero te hará falta una función auxiliar que *parsee* el `stringstream`.